# Triple boot questions/issues

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot

I was running Win 7 and Ubuntu 18.04 as dual boot. No issues, Grub was working fine. Decided it was time to try Win 10. Bought Home version directly from Microsoft. I shrank the Win 7 partition to get ~150 GB for Win 10. All three OS would be on one drive. Installation of Win 10 went fine. Was prepared to fix Grub. Followed an online guide to do this. I think it worked but I didn’t realize it was OK (see below). Tried to “fix” and really messed it up. Could only get the grub prompt. So reinstalled Ubuntu choosing to replace existing Ubuntu installation. That went OK and now Grub was back.

Now for the issue. When Grub comes up it shows Ubuntu and Windows 10 as choices. No Windows 7. It shows Win 10 in /dev/sda1. This is where Win 7 is. I installed Win 10 in /dev/sda2. So, did Win 10 put its bootloader in different partition than its own?

Behavior: If I choose Ubuntu it goes to Ubuntu. Good! If I choose Windows 10 I get a Windows screen that asked if I want to boot to Windows 10 or Windows 7. If I choose Win 10 I go directly to Win 10. Good! If I choose Win 7, after several seconds, it goes back to the Grub menu. If I choose Win 10 again, I go directly to Win 7. Yep, two rounds to get Win 7. A mild pain, but now I know how it works. Question. Is there something I could have done differently with the Win 10 install so everything would have been separate? Would it have required a separate drive for Win 10 with the other disconnected? Is there anything I can do now? I could remove Win 10 and Ubuntu at this point and reinstall them, but what about the Win 7 bootloader? I don't have a rescue disc/USB.

I am new to Win 10 so maybe this next part is just the way it is. If I am in Windows 7 I have four drive letters. C, D & E are optical drives, and F. F appears to be mostly Win 10 folders (Documents is linked back to local C). If I am in Windows 10 I have drive letters C, D, and F & G. F & G are optical drives. D appears to be Windows 7. There is no E! Seems as if Windows 10 kind of blended the two OS.

I hope this post is in the right place this time. Thanks

Help with any of this is appreciated.

Comment: Windows 10 has a new feature upgrade that re-write the operating system every 6 to 9 months. What I do is run Windows 10 Pro (Home is cripple if you wish to do business things with it), VMware Workstation, and then Windows 7 Pro, Ubuntu 18 LTS, Kali and other guests. This works very well and avoids the issues you are having. Windows 10 has multiple partitions to allow it to rebuild itself

Comment: That's pretty much standard. Windows 7 and Windows 10 don't boot the same way, so the computer needs to reboot to get back to Win7. I don't believe there's a workaround to this. If you have your license for win7 you can simply download the ISO of your version and create a bootable disk of it.

Comment: FYI: You could have used you Windows 7 key to install Windows 10 for free.

Comment: I think you should keep the way it is !!!  but another method if you like will be to use Windows bootloader to boot into any of the windows or Linux